# Symfony 1.4 cookie issue

Tags: php, cookies, symfony-1.4, session-cookies

I am trying to find where Symfony is setting a cookie. When I visit my site (I'm using the sfDoctrineGuard plugin) I get the login page, which is the expected behaviour. When viewing the cookies that have been created, there is a 'symfony' cookie. I can't find where Symfony is setting this cookie... I need to change the expiry time.

The only places that I see setCookie being used is for the Remember Me key but this is a separate cookie altogether.

The other problem is that for some reason, the expiry time for the 'symfony' cookie is showing as "Session" in Safari, and not a date/time.

I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with sfDoctrineGuard, and that Symfony always creates a cookie when a user visits the site, just need to find the code that is setting this cookie.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the timeout of the session in the `factories.yml`

```
storage:
  class: sfSessionStorage
  param:
    session_name: symfony
    session_cookie_lifetime: 60000 # number of seconds
```

[Documentation here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_sub_session_set_cookie_params_parameters)

Comment: And this works even if a user hasn't logged in? I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith yes the cookie is used to store the session id - doesnt matter if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Adding "session_name: syfmony" and a lifetime param in my factories has fixed the expiry, it is no longer session. I wasn't sure if this would work as I'm using PDOSessionStorage but apparently it has. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith PDOSessionStorage deals with the server side - the cookie just contains a session id - this is sent to the server in a request - Symfony gets the session id, then looks it up and sees if there is a matching session. PDOSessionStorage deals with the getting and setting of the server side ...

Answer (score 2):

On your `factories.yml` try

```
all:
  storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name:            The cookie name (symfony by default)
      session_id:              The session id (null by default)
      auto_start:              Whether to start the session (true by default)
      session_cookie_lifetime: Cookie lifetime
      session_cookie_path:     Cookie path
      session_cookie_domain:   Cookie domain
      session_cookie_secure:   Cookie secure
      session_cookie_httponly: Cookie http only (only for PHP >= 5.2)
```